# casting Integer Object to double throwing error

Tags: java

I am trying to write a 'Cup' class which implements the Comparable interface.

My code:

```
class Cup<T> implements Comparable<T>{

    public T radius;
    public T height;

    public Cup(T radius, T height){
        this.radius = radius;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public double getVolume(){

        return (double) radius * (double) radius* (double) height* 3.14 ; // throwing error 
    }

    public int compareTo(Object cup){

        if(getVolume()== ((Cup) cup).getVolume()){ // cannot access java.lang.Comparable
            return 0;
        }
        else if(getVolume() > ((Cup) cup).getVolume()){
            return 1;
        }
        else if(getVolume() < ((Cup) cup).getVolume()){
            return -1;
        }
        return -2;
    }
}

class test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Cup<Integer> mycup = new Cup<Integer>(5,5);

        Cup<Integer> momscup = new Cup<Integer>(7,7);

        mycup.compareTo(momscup);

    }
}
```

But the program throws error stating: 
`java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to class java.lang.Double`.

**I am NOT trying to cast to Double, but to double. Why is it throwing the error?**

Thanks

Comment: Define the class as `implements Comparable<Cup<T>>`, to get rid of the need to cast (and the raw types) in `compareTo`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am NOT trying to cast to Double, but to double. Why is it throwing the error?

The root of your problem is that the static type of `T` is `Object` not `Integer`.   So the compiler has determined that the following path may work:

1. Cast the object's actual type to `Double` (which requires a runtime check)
2. Unbox the `Double` to a `double`.

The problem is that `Integer` cannot be cast to `Double`.

The best solution is this:

```
class Cup<T extends Number> implements Comparable<T> {
    ...
    public double getVolume(){
        return radius.doubleValue() * radius.doubleValue() 
               height.doubleValue() * Math.PI;
    }
```

which is statically type-safe (modulo any unsafe conversions that you might do elsewhere).

---

Note that if `T` was replaced by `Integer`, the compiler would use a different path for the conversion:

1. Unbox the `Integer` to an `int`.
2. Widen the `int` to a `double`.

Depending on exactly how you wrote the πr<sup>2</sup>h expression, the type casts may be unnecessary.

Comment: What is a static type? When I print the `radius.getClass()` it prints `Integer`, not `object`.

Comment: The static type is the type that the compiler thinks that `T` is.

Comment: In your example, `T` is a type variable, so the static type for the purposes of working out how to perform the type cast is the erasure of `T`; i.e. `java.lang.Object`.  When we add the `extends Number`, that changes the erasure to `Number`.

Comment: `radius.getClass()` is printing the actual class, not the static class.

Comment: I actually studied the whole generics official documentation. I have a few queries. I posted a question and my understanding there but haven't really gotten any response. Would be great if you could have a glimpse. thanks [Click here for the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55783070/erasure-type-and-bridging-method-clarification)

Answer (score 2):

By what you are doing is actually implicitly adding a cast to `Double` and because of this you are getting the exception.

I'd suggest you few changes after which your class looks like this:

```java
class Cup<T extends Number> implements Comparable<Cup<T>> {

    public T radius;
    public T height;

    public Cup(T radius, T height) {
        this.radius = radius;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public double getVolume() {
        return radius.doubleValue() * radius.doubleValue() * height.doubleValue() * 3.14;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Cup<T> cup) {
        return Double.compare(getVolume(), cup.getVolume());
    }
}
```

Closely look how I've changed the `compareTo` method and the `getVolume` method to make it more readable.

And after these changes you don't get when running the test:

```java
class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cup<Integer> mycup = new Cup<>(5, 5);
        Cup<Integer> momscup = new Cup<>(7, 7);
        mycup.compareTo(momscup);
    }
}
```

The following are the changes that I'd suggest you so that you can learn.

- From Effective Java Item 31, you should use bounded wildcards to increase the API flexibility. (Read the generics chapter from Effective Java, it will be highly helpful)
- Use `Double.compare`, it's a convenient method already given to do what exactly you want.
- Use `@Override` if you are overriding a method.
- `Cup<Integer> mycup = new Cup<>(5, 5);` While initialization you again don't need to mention `Integer` on the right-hand side. (This can be done if you are using JDK 7 or higher)

Comment: Thats what my question is, why is it implicitly adding a cast to Double?

Answer (score 0):

radius and height properties are defined as T, but you cast them to double, you should declare them as double or make the Generic type of the class extends Number which is the abstract parent class of Double and Integer

```
class Cup<T extends Number> {

    public T radius;
    public T height;

    public Cup(T radius, T height) {
        this.radius = radius;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public double getVolume() {

        return radius.doubleValue() * radius.doubleValue() * height.doubleValue() * 3.14; // throwing error 
    }

}

class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Cup<Integer> mycup = new Cup<Integer>(5, 5);

        Cup<Integer> momscup = new Cup<Integer>(7, 7);

        System.out.println(mycup.getVolume());
    }
}
```