# Erasure type and Bridging Method clarification

Tags: java, generics, erasure, java-bridge-method

The code following is taken from Oracle documentation of generics -

```
 class Node<T> {

    public T data;

    public Node(T data) { this.data = data; }

    public void setData(T data) {
        System.out.println("Node.setData");
        this.data = data;
    }
}

 class MyNode extends Node<Integer> {
    public MyNode(Integer data) { super(data); }

    public void setData(Integer data) {
        System.out.println("MyNode.setData");
        super.setData(data);
    }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         MyNode mn = new MyNode(5);
         Node n = mn;            // A raw type - compiler throws an unchecked warning
         n.setData("Hello");
         Integer x = mn.data;  // Causes a ClassCastException to be thrown.
     }
}
```

My understanding of this code -

**Q - is method `setData` overrided or overloaded?**

my under standing - because `MyNode` is extending `Node<Integer>`, the value of type parameter `T` is set to `Integer`.

so class `Node` has method `setData(Integer data)`  as T= Integer
and class `MyNode` has method `setData(Integer data)`.

It is **overriding** as signature is same.

**Q- is the method setData Overrided even after Erasure?** 
My understanding -

after we erase `<T>` the set method becomes in `Node` becomes, `setData(Object data)`

and the set method of `Mynode` will be - `setData(Integer data)` as there is no type parameter, nothing to remove.

But this is **overloading**.

**Q - we wanted overloading or overriding?**

My understanding - by the looks of methods defined before erasure, **we wanted overriding**.

**Q - So how to achieve Overiding after Erasure?**

My understanding - By **Bridging Method**. for example:

```
setData(Object data){
    setData((Integer) Data);
}
```

**Is my understanding correct?**

**Also,  `class MyNode extends Node<Integer>` when does `Integer` is passed down to `<T>` ? when super is called?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, the method `setData` is overridden.
2. From the point of view of the user, it will look as if `setData(T data)` is overridden by `setData(Integer i)`, i.e. when you invoke `setData(42)`, it will print something with *"MyNode"*, not with *"Node"*.

   On the level of type erased method signatures, this will be achieved by a synthetic bridge method `setData(Object)` added to `MyNode`, i.e. if you decompile `MyNode.class` with `javap`, you will see *two* methods:

   ```
     public void setData(java.lang.Integer);
     public void setData(java.lang.Object);
   ```
3. The language spec says *"override"*, I don't know why anyone would want something else.
4. It's not clear what you mean by *"achieve overriding after erasure"*. The type erasure comes after the type checking and determining what overrides what. There is nothing to "achieve", it's just the order in which things work (see also [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43901283/type-erasure-and-overriding-generic-method?rq=1#comment74837023_43901283)). The synthetic bridging method that overrides the original `setData(Object)` looks like what you wrote (up to minor typos):

   ```
   setData(Object data){
       setData((Integer) data);
   }
   ```

   at least that's what [the documentation says](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bridgeMethods.html). But this is a *synthetic* method, it is generated by the compiler automatically. If it appeared in the source code, it would give you compilation errors.

Comment: isn't the synthetic bridging method generated because,  after erasure the class nodes setData = `setData(Object Data)` and the Class MyNode's setData = `setData( Integer Data)`. But they were meant to be Overriden. So compiler provides a `setData(Object Data)` in MyNode which would call `setData(Integer Data)` ?

Comment: @lynxx I'm not sure what you wanted to ask in this comment. I think your problem is that you are confusing Java the Language and the JVM. These are two separate entities. JVM has its own notion of "method", and its own notion of "override". Java's "method" and "override" are closely related, but nonetheless different. Java's generics is one case where you see the difference: one single Java method mysteriously splits into two JVM methods. That's just a minor implementation detail. It might be useful occasionally when debugging certain errors, but is otherwise not even that important.

Comment: @lynxx Note that there are also other languages targeting the JVM. For example, Scala's "method" will again be slightly different, and because it has all kind of fancy stuff like singleton-objects, traits, and mixin composition, it will generate tons of synthetic JVM classes and JVM methods. If you look at the output of the Scala compiler, you'll often see that it generates fifty JVM `.class` files for a single Scala "class". This is entirely normal. Again, those are just some implementation details, that are usually not very important.

Comment: `After type erasure, the method signatures do not match. The Node method becomes setData(Object) and the MyNode method becomes setData(Integer). Therefore, the MyNode setData method does not override the Node setData method.(Oracle docs) ` This is what I was talking about in the point 2, that after erasure it the method looks like it is being `Overloaded` but in reality it should be `Overrided`, Hence compiler provides a bridging method to make the Overloaded method, Overrided. **Thanks for all your replies!!**